# Is it possible to dynamically set the schema in Spring Repository @Query annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, kotlin

I have an existing database that separates out teams into separate schemas with the same table structure inside them (ugly, I know). I need to accept the team name as parameter in a get request and dynamically query the appropriate schema for that data.

I've tried setting the Schema with a query parameter to prevent SQL injection, but I've read you're not allowed to set a schema/table with these.

I've created this sample of how my code is set up:

```
Entity:

@Entity
@Immutable
data class UserEntity (
   @Id
   @Column(name = "userId")
   var userId: String,

   @Column(name = "phone")
   var phone: String
)

-------------------

Controller:

@GetMapping("/getPhoneFromCorrectSchema"
fun getPhoneFromCorrectSchema(
   @RequestParam(value = "userId") userId: String,
   @RequestParam(value = "teamName") teamName: String
) : String {
   return userRepo.getPhoneFromCorrectSchema(use( rId, teamName)
}

---------------------
Repository:

iterface UserRepo : CrudRepository<UserEntity, String> {
 @Query(nativeQuery = true,
        value = "SELECT * FROM :teamName.USER_TABLE WHERE userId = :userId"
 )
 fun getPhoneFromCorrectSchema(@Param("userId") userId: String, @Param("teamName") teamName: String) : UserEntity
}
```

Comment: did you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Its looks ugly and I don’t have any clear solution but i can tell you if you use :teamName.USER_TABLE it do not try to resolve  ‘teamName’, it will try to resolve ‘teamName.USER_TABLE’. Instead of passing teamName only and appending ‘.TableName’, you can try passing teamName plus tableName as a single parameter. It may work.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but this doesn't seem to working